# How to extract strings using regex

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have string that contains some values which seperated with `#` and `<>` , I need to fetch all values with regex. 
a sample of data is:

```
#4<...>
```

and below you can see an exmple of main string:

```
string s = "#0<Every word comes here>#1<...>#2<...>#3<...>#4<...>#5<...>#6<...>#7<...>#8<...>#9<...>#A<...>#B<...>#C<...>#D<...>#E<...>#F<...>";
```

Comment: SO isn't a code writing service. Have you *tried* something? What special characters are you talking about? `#`, `<` and `>` aren't special characters. It looks like you want to capture any character between `#< ` and `>`. Have you tried using *that* as a pattern?

Comment: i need a pattern to get string like this:  #4<...> ,But I can not write the pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string str = "#0<Every word comes here>#1<...>#2<...>#3<...>#4<...>#5<...>#6<...>#7<...>#8<...>#9<...>#A<...>#B<...>#C<...>#D<...>#E<...>#F<...>";
var regex = new Regex(@"(?s)\#\d<(.+?)>");
foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(str))
{
    var value = match.Value;
    var words = match.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

Comment: `regex.Matches()`  only get values from 0 to 9 and do not get values A to F.

Comment: Yes. Change `\d` to `\w`

Answer (score 0):

If you are exactly want to get #4<...> then use this:

```
    #4(.+?)>
```

Or if you want all #x<...> then use this:

```
    #[1-9A-Z](.+?)>
```

This should be the simplest solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

**Short Version**

Use `#(?<key>[0-9A-F])<(?<tag>.*?)>` and access the `key` and `tag` named groups by their actual names :

```
var regex = new Regex("#(?<key>[0-9A-F])<(?<tag>.*?)>");

var matches=regex.Matches(s);
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", match.Groups["key"].Value, match.Groups["tag"].Value);
}
```

**Long explanation**

Regular expressions are powerful but not exactly easy to use, if one doesn't understand how they work. .NET documentation contains a very good section on Regular Expressions, including a [Quick Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference)

A first attempt would be to catch everything between `<` and `>`. To catch any single character, you use `.`. To catch 0 or many instances of a pattern like `.`, , you use `*`. One or more is matched by `+`.

A first attempt would be to use `<.*>`. That would fail though and catch everything from the first `<` up to the last `>`. That's because regular expressions use greedy matching by default - they capture as many matching characters as possible.

To catch as few characters as possible, ie to use non-greedy matching, the symbol `?` should be added after `*` or `+`. The pattern `<.*?>` would return one match for each `< >` pair and its contents.

The tags aren't needed though. Rather than use string manipulation to clear the match, we can group the characters inside each tags  so we can access them as a single group. This is done by surrounding the pattern with parentheses, eg `<(.*?)>`.  Grouping is described in detail in [Grouping Constructs in Regular Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions)

Groups can be named, which makes reading the desired value a *lot* easier. Such groups are called "named groups". Named groups are defined by adding `?<somename>` after the opening parenthesis.

The tag contents can be captured into the `tag` group with this pattern : `<(?<tag>.*?)>`.

Capturing the key is easy when named groups are used. The key can be captured by the pattern `#(?<key>.)` This would catch possibly invalid keys though, like `#Z`. To match only a specific set of characters, a character group is defined by placing all characters inside square brackets, eg `[12A]`. Ranges can be used as well. To match characters 0-9 and A-G, the group would have to be `[0-9A-F]`.

The full pattern that catches both key and value, and returns them in named groups is :

```
#(?<key>[0-9A-F])<(?<tag>.*?)>
```

Named groups can be accessed by name using the the [Match.Groups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups(v=vs.110).aspx) property

An example :

```
var s = "#0<Every word comes here>#1<...>#2<...>#3<...>#4<...>#5<...>#6<...>#7<...>#8<...>#9<...>#A<...>#B<...>#C<...>#D<...>#E<...>#F<...>";
var regex = new Regex("#(?<key>[0-9A-F])<(?<tag>.*?)>");

var matches=regex.Matches(s);
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", match.Groups["key"].Value, match.Groups["tag"].Value);
}
```

Named groups allow the use of LINQ to process matches, filter them, and generate, eg a dictionary of key/value pairs, eg:

```
var pairDictionary = (from Match match in regex.Matches(s)
                      let pair= new { Key   = match.Groups["key"].Value, 
                                      Value = match.Groups["tag"].Value
                                    }
                      where pair.Key != "A"
                      select pair
                     ).ToDictionary(pair=>pair.Key, pair=>pair.Value);
```